# Asp.net Core EF Update

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I used EF in Asp.net Core, but I got below error when trying to Update.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The instance of entity type 'TodoItem' cannot
>   be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is
>   already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a
>   unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if
>   the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you
>   are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not
>   collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other
>   new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

Here is my Update Code:

```
    public class TodoRepository : ITodoRepository
{
    private readonly TodoContext _context;

    public TodoRepository(TodoContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        //initialize database
        Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Item1" });
        //Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Item2" });
        //Add(new TodoItem { Name = "Item3" });
    }

    public IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetAll()
    {
       return _context.TodoItems.AsNoTracking().ToList();
    }

    public void Add(TodoItem item)
    {
        _context.TodoItems.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public TodoItem Find(long key)
    {
        return _context.TodoItems.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == key);
    }

    public void Remove(long key)
    {
        var entity = _context.TodoItems.AsNoTracking().First(t => t.Key == key);
        _context.TodoItems.Remove(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update(TodoItem item)
    {
        _context.TodoItems.Update(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

As you could find, I already have tried **AsNoTracking**, and I also tried it in Startup.cs.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //inject repository into DI container, use database in memory
    services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase().UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));

    //inject repository into DI container, and use sql databse
    //services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options=>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));


    //The first generic type represents the type (typically an interface) that will be requested from the container. 
    //The second generic type represents the concrete type that will be instantiated by the container and used to fulfill such requests.
    services.AddSingleton<ITodoRepository, TodoRepository>();

    //add mvc service to container, this is conventional routing
    //This also applys to web api which is Attribute Routing
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: one more update, if I inject TodoContext todoContext into my controller, and use `            _todoContext.TodoItems.Update(todoItem);
            _todoContext.SaveChanges();
`, it works. I do not know why it did not work under my TodoRepository.

Comment: Have you tried change db entry state ? line 44 https://github.com/hherzl/Northwind/blob/master/SourceCode/Northwind.Core/DataLayer/Repository.cs

Comment: You are working in memory? How values of Todoitem.Key are generated? InMemory does not have any sequence support, so all your TodoItems are with Key==0 if you do not assign them anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing **services.AddDbContext** to **services.AddScoped** which has been pointed out in below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection